# How to Use Variable as location url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kml, filereader

**Hello guys How to replace the location of file URL into variable?**

```
NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
                    $scope.map = map;
                    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({ map: map });
                    myParser.parse('cta.kml');
                });
```

**myParser.parse is only accepting url but not variable? is this possible?**

```
    var result = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<!-- Data derived from:
       Ed Knittel - || tastypopsicle.com
       Feel free to use this file for your own purposes.
       Just leave the comments and credits when doing so.
-->
  <Document>
    <name>Chicago Transit Map</name>
    <description>Chicago Transit Authority train lines</description>

    <Style id="blueLine">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ffff0000</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="redLine">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>" ........ so on...
```

**how to replace myParser.parse(result)????**

im using ngMap.

Answer (score 0):

> myParser.parse is only accepting url but not variable? is this possible?

No.

```
NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
    $scope.map = map;
    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({ map: map });
    var myUrl = 'cta.kml'; 
    myParser.parse(myUrl);
});
```

should be possible.

However: Not quite sure, if that was your question?

Comment: myParser.parse(result) how to do it? because "result" is variable